# Why does ensureCapacity() in Java ArrayList extend the capacity with a const 1.5 or (oldCapacity * 3)/2 + 1?

Tags: java, arraylist, capacity

Why does ensureCapacity() in Java ArrayList extend the capacity with a const 1.5 or (oldCapacity * 3)/2 + 1?

Comment: A very similar question asked here might help you out: [Logic used in ensureCapacity method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336291/logic-used-in-ensurecapacity-method-in-arraylist)

Answer (score 2):

It helps mitigate the exponential increase in time that would result if the array was expanded by one element instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array with a small capacity even 0 and you small capacities need to grow relatively quickly.